# Can't convert birthday into string facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, object, facebook-php-sdk

I'm testing facebook php sdk.
I have permissions for 'user_birthday,email'and default user profile.
Here is the code.

```
<?php
if(isset($session)) {

  try {

$user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'GET', '/me/'
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

   var_dump ($user_profile);
   echo $user_profile->getEmail();
   $_SESSION['user']=$user_profile->getName();
   $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_profile->getId();

    $_SESSION['profile_pic']="http://graph.facebook.com/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/picture";
   $_SESSION['gender']=$user_profile->getGender();

 $vars = get_object_vars ( $user_profile->getBirthday() );


 print_r ( $vars );


 } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }   

}        
?>
```

And Output is

```
    object(Facebook\GraphUser)[6]
    protected 'backingData' => 
    array (size=12)
    'id' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxx' (length=15)
    'birthday' => string '01/12/1990' (length=10)
    'email' => string 'xxxxx@gmail.com' (length=19)
    'first_name' => string 'xxxx' (length=10)
    'gender' => string 'male' (length=4)
    'last_name' => string 'xxxx' (length=4)
    'link' => string 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxxx/' (length=60)
    'locale' => string 'en_US' (length=5)
    'name' => string 'xxxxx xxxxx' (length=15)
    'timezone' => int -8
    'updated_time' => string '2015-02-22T07:48:23+0000' (length=24)
    'verified' => boolean true

     xxxxx@gmail.comArray ( [date] => 1993-04-22 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )
```

Problem is,I can't use the birthday object.
when I checked the birthday with echo,

```
    echo $user_profile->getBirthday();
```

I got this error.

```
     Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

when I dumped the $user_profile->getBirthday();
output is.

```
      object(DateTime)[9]
      public 'date' => string '1993-04-22 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

How can I get the Birthday as string?
 I'm new to php.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object's [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method:

```
$user_profile->getBirthday()->format('m/d/Y');
```

See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for help on constructing the preferred format string.

Comment: the code you provided works on mozilla firefox.But when I tested on internet explorer and chrome.I got the following error."Call to a member function format() on a non-object".So I change the code to "date_create($user_profile->getBirthday())->format('Y/m/d'); " That works on internet explorer and chrome.But same error on Mozilla Firefox.Any Ideas?

Comment: @Lod_Blade: Since this is server-side code, it should not depend on the browser at all. Have you made sure you’re getting a birthday value from the API in each case to begin with?

Comment: Sorry.I know that sounds crazy,I've got the answer.I'm testing different browsers with several facebook accounts.Maybe I got that error because the accounts I'm testing have different privacy settings.

Comment: @chris-l, you are just awesome :) Your method work perfectly for me after 5 hours stack !